# apt-get not installing packages on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 18.04

I was trying to install `alien` package:

```
mkj@mkj-ThinkPad-E470:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install alien
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package alien


mkj@mkj-ThinkPad-E470:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I observed that no package installation is happening. Here is my `source.list`:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection that machine?

Comment: yes i have internet

Answer (score 0):

Found this when having the same issue:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
sudo apt-get update
```

https://itsfoss.com/solve-ubuntu-error-failed-to-download-repository-information-check-your-internet-connection/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and the problem was due to Kaspersky. I killed Kaspersky and WSL had no issue running `sudo apt update`.

Comment: _Kyle Misner_, I don't see the original poster told us they were using Kaspersky in Windows, nor do I see them state they were running Ubuntu under Windows; they could be running Ubuntu on bare metal for all we know. Suggest you ask them if they are running WSL, and if so, which Windows antivirus app (if any), before giving a WSL-specific answer.

Comment: I suppose the answer could be more genericized to state that they should verify if they are using an antivirus of any sort, no matter which OS they are running. If so, try disabling that antivirus to verify if that is the culprit causing the issue.

Comment: I am running ubuntu in a stand alone system